# Pygame on mac error with loading images

Tags: python, image, macos, bitmap, pygame

I recently started programming on pygame, I use python 3.5.1 and the latest pygame and when I load a bitmap(bmp) it puts it on the screen like this

[image]

At school when I program on the computer it works fine just on my macbook pro 13'' with el capitain

```
import pygame    #imports pygame

width = 550     #width is 550

height = 420    #height is 420

size = width, height # size is a tuple

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

white = 255,225,255 

screen.fill(white)

gameOn = True

mario = pygame.image.load("mario.bmp") #load the bitmap

marioflip = pygame.transform.flip(mario, True, True)

screen.blit(marioflip, (0,0)) # add it to screen

marioscale = pygame.transform.scale(mario, (50,50))

screen.blit(marioscale, (250,250))

mariorotate = pygame.transform.rotate(mario, 45)

screen.blit(mariorotate,(350,0))

while gameOn:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 

            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: @furas i tried already it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing a known bug in SDL_image on that version of OS X. See this link for details and a workaround:

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated